# How to continue with a script only after it was received by a TCPClient?

Tags: c#, tcp

I thought about sending a packet with one byte to the server and to write on the serverside the following code:

```
int a= stream.ReadByte()
if(a==-1){
//client received data 
}
```

The stream is a NetworkStream 
I want to do this because after this I start a timer on the server. The timer should only start if the clients have updated their values.

Comment: Please expand this with an explanation of the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Why do you think it's not received?

Comment: Do you still wnat me to explain more of my problem? @500-InternalServerError

Comment: I don't think it's not received the question is when it's received @CaiusJard

Comment: The question title is "How to check whether data was received by TCPClient?" - *whether* implies "it was/it wasn't" i.e. the client sent some data and it did/didn't arrive; it's nothing to do with the time an event occurs. I ask why you think it isn't because TCP is a reliable transport mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Stream` only has limited options:

- it can return a *positive* number to say "yes, I have provided this much data"
- it can return a *non-positive* number to say "EOF: I have no data, and *never will* have more data"

  - (the above also map similarly to `ReadByte()`, except the second point becomes "negative" for no data)
- it can block, waiting for one of the above two conditions to be possible
- it can throw an exception

What it *can't* do is say "I currently do not have data, but I might in the future". As such, you can't use the `Stream` API to check whether there *is* data. Instead, it is typical to use an async API (usually on the `Socket` itself, or another abstraction that isn't `Stream`), to allow you to process a callback *when* data becomes available. There is also the `.Available` property  on a `.Socket` which tells you the amount of data currently buffered and available for consumption (note: this API is typically only used to choose between sync vs async IO).

Comment: I know the NetworkStream.Read() method waits until it received data. Does the NetworkStream.ReadByte() method work the same way but only reads one byte?

Comment: @solelyme yes; as does `Peek()`; hence what I was saying about using an async callback, or checking `.Available`